# Finding the Isomomorphism(honomorphism) from $S_n$ to $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

To find the homomorphsim $\tau$ (or isomorphism $\phi$), Only just I do is observing the mapping of the generator of the group. Plus, the group $S_n = \langle (1,2),(1,2,...,n) \rangle = \langle (1,2),(1,3),...,(1,n) \rangle$

Let me take the case for $n=3$

It is well known fact that the number of the homomorphsim is $10$, isomorphism is $6$ considering the generator $S_3 = \langle (1,2),(1,2,3) \rangle $

So, I tried different way considering the generator $S_3 = \langle (1,2),(1,3) \rangle$

First isomorphism $\phi : S_3 \to S_3 $, Each generating set of $S_3$ maps to another generating set of $S_3$

Therefore, there are two cases firstly "$\phi(1,2) =(1,2) $ and $\phi(1,3) =(1,3)$" Secondly  "$\phi(1,2) =(1,3) $ and $\phi(1,3) =(1,2)$".

So there are two isomorphism $S_3 \to S_3$ contradicted with the answer is $6$

Second homomorphism $\tau : S_3 \to S_3$, both of the the order of the $\tau(1,2)$ and $\tau(1,3)$ should be divisor of the $2$.

Hence $\tau (1,2), \tau (1,3) \in \{id,  (1,3), (1,2), (2,3) \} $. The number of the homomorphism is $16$

Again this is contradict with the fact that $10$

I confidently do say my answer $2$ and $16$ is wrong, But the problem is I can't find which point I was wrong.

Any advice and answer always appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: " Each generator(transposition) maps to another generator" - this is confused. Each generating set may map to another generating set: so you need to worry also about the possibility $\phi((12))=(23)$ etc etc.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Thanks for your comment, I revised the part "Each generator ~another generator" in my post reflecting your comment. It seems I need to more  consider the case the maps to another generator like $\phi(1,2)= (2,3)$  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $\tau(1,2)=e$ (where $e$ is the identity), then $$\tau(1,2,3)=\tau((1,2)(1,3))=\tau(1,2)\tau(1,3)=\tau(1,3)$$ but $\tau(1,2,3)$ has order dividing three while $\tau(1,3)$ has order dividing two, so they both must have order one, that is, necessarily $\tau(1,3)=e$, whence $\tau$ is the trivial homomorphism mapping everything to the identity. That cuts down your count of homomorphisms considerably.